# Solve the eqation $a^3+2b^3+4c^3=6abc+1$

Tags: number-theory

Find all integers $a,b,c>2010$ so that $a^3+2b^3+4c^3=6abc+1$.
If there are no solutions then prove it.

As for now I only tried to use the identity $x^3+y^3+z^3-3xyz=(x+y+z)(x^2+y^2+z^2-xy-yz-zx)$, but I get some irational numbers which make it hard to solve it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is treated in section $4$ of the article [Cubic' Pell's equation](http://www.ungaforskare.org/sites/default/files/files/projektbanken/cubic_pells_equation_-_lund_-_tien_truong.pdf), where the authors solve
$$x^3+cy^3+c^2z^3=3cxyz+1.$$ 
For $c=2$ this gives your equation.

Comment: Section 4.3.3 presents "An Algorithm that Does Not Always Work".  I don't see a general method.  Am I missing something?